# Не добавляется класс при событии onclick

Tags: javascript

```js
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");
var li = ul.querySelectorAll("li");
var t;
ul.onclick = function(e) {
  var target = e.target;
  if (target.tagName = "LI") {
    home(target);
    return;
  };

};

function home(node) {
  t = node;
  t.classList("oli") // не добавляется класс при нажатии
}
```

```css
.oli {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Первый</li>
  <li>Второй</li>
  <li>Третий</li>
  <li>Четвертый</li>
  <li>Пятый</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Неправильное использование classList
Верно будет
`classList.add('class');`

Answer (score 0):

Как можно найти [в справке](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

`classList` - Это коллекция, а не функция. Поэтому при попытке использовать ее как функцию получается соответствующее исключение: *classList is not a function*

Там же в справке, присутствует [список методов](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Methods) присутствующих у данной коллекции

Для добавления нужно использовать метод *add*.

```js
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");
var li = ul.querySelectorAll("li");
var t;
ul.onclick = function(e) {
  var target = e.target;
  if (target.tagName = "LI") {
    home(target);
    return;
  };

};

function home(node) {
  t = node;
  t.classList.add("oli") // не добавляется класс при нажатии
}
```

```css
.oli {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Первый</li>
  <li>Второй</li>
  <li>Третий</li>
  <li>Четвертый</li>
  <li>Пятый</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

`classList` - это не функция, а объект [`DOMTokenList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList) ([см. также](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)).

```js
console.info(typeof document.querySelector('div').classList); // object
```

```html
<div></div>
```

**Методы**:
`add()` - Добавляет значение к объекту `DOMTokenList`, если такового не имеется.

`contains()` - Проверяет, содержит ли объект `DOMTokenList` передаваемое значение или нет.

`item()` - Возвращает значение по указанному индексу.

`remove()` - Удаляет значение из объекта `DOMTokenList`, если таковое имеется.

`toggle()` - Если `DOMTokenList` содержит переданное в метод значение, оно удалится, в противном случае - добавится.

Их больше, но это наиболее используемые.

**Свойства**:
`length` - Количество элементов(или символов).